# A $S^1$ invariant frame on $S^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, hopf-fibration

We  consider  the  action $S^1$ on $S^3$  with  $\alpha.(z_1,z_2)=(\alpha z_1, \alpha z_2)$  where $\alpha \in S^1,\;(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2 \; \text{with} \; |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1$.

> Are there three independent vector fields $S_1, S_2, S_3$ on $S^3$ such that each $S_i$ is  invariant under action of  $S^1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $S^3=Sp(1)\subset\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}j$ and right-multiply by $i,j,k$.  Then the left multiplication by $S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ commutes with the right-multiplication, so you have $S^1$-invariant.